# Can you use chlorine bleach and baking powder in a dishwasher for mold / grime?

Tags: cleaning

I used a bit in the wash, but my dishwasher wound up sudsing. Did I just use too much? There was some baking powder in there as well.

Comment: Don’t do stuff like this. It sounds like the baking soda reacted with an ammonia compound from the soap residue.  Your problem is likely more from the baking soda than the bleach.  In any case, don’t mix household chemicals.

Comment: I use sodium percarbonate to get rid of mold and mildew in my dishwasher. I add it at the start of the wash cycle (not prewash).

Comment: Baking powder =/= baking soda. The former contains starch and other things not suited to cleaning duty. Which did you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Dishwashers are especially prone to over suddsing.  The Clorox is going to soften the water to such an extent the even the proper soap will over suds. Dish washer detergent is designed specifically to retard the formation of bubbles.